# Change dynamically sub layout on radio selection

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

Sorry if I ask silly question, but so far had no luck in figuring out this one. I have form with 2 radio buttons that decide layout and used components of layout bellow them. Here is one of the layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arrival_date_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/arrival_date_label"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/arrival_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/arrival_date_label"
            android:hint="10/05/2012"/>
    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/arrival_time_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/arrival_date"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/return_date_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/return_date_label"
            android:layout_below="@id/arrival_time_spinner"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/return_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/return_date_label"
            android:hint="10/05/2012"/>
    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/return_time_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/return_date"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and Java class to initialize some of the components used

```
public class ReturnFixedDays extends RelativeLayout {
    private EditText arrivalDate;
    private Spinner arrivalTime;
    private EditText returnDate;
    private Spinner returnTime;
    private final String pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    public ReturnFixedDays(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.return_fixed_days, null);

        arrivalDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.arrival_date);
        arrivalDate.setText(arrivalDate());

        arrivalTime = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.arrival_time_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.array.travel_time_entries,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        arrivalTime.setAdapter(adapter);

        returnDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.return_date);
        returnDate.setText(returnDate());

        returnTime = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.return_time_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.array.travel_time_entries,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        returnTime.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    private String arrivalDate(){
        return dateToString(today());
    }

    private String returnDate(){
        return dateToString(weekLater());
    }

    private String dateToString(Date date){
        return formatter().format(date);
    }

    private SimpleDateFormat formatter(){
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    }

    private Date weekLater(){
        return adjustDateBy(today(), 7);
    }

    private Date today(){
        return Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    private Date adjustDateBy(Date currentDate, int numOfDays) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(currentDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, numOfDays);

        return calendar.getTime();

    }

}
```

Now to add this layout to view I do as following in xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dates_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/flight_layout">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_label"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dates_label"
                style="@style/Label"/>
        <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/dates_radio_group"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@id/date_label">
            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/flexible_dates_radio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/flexible_dates_label"
                    style="@style/Label"/>
            <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/fixed_dates_radio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/fixed_dates_label"
                    style="@style/Label"/>
        </RadioGroup>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/stub_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/dates_layout">

        <com.flyweekend.android.date.view.ReturnFixedDays
                android:id="@+id/return_fixed_days_stub"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout="@layout/return_fixed_days"/>

        <com.flyweekend.android.date.view.ReturnFlexibleDays
                android:id="@+id/return_flexible_days_stub"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout="@layout/return_flexible_days"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

FlightView.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        dateTypeRadioGrp = dateTypeRadioGroup(view);
        returnFixedDays = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.return_fixed_days_stub);
        updateDatesVisibility();
        return view;
    }

private RadioGroup dateTypeRadioGroup(View view){
        RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.dates_radio_group);
        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int selected) {
                if(selected == R.id.flexible_dates_radio){
                    Log.i(TAG, "Flexible dates selected");
                    updateDatesVisibility();
                }else{
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fixed dates selected");
                    updateDatesVisibility();
                }
            }
        });
        return group;
    }

    private void updateDatesVisibility(){
        if(dateTypeRadioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.fixed_dates_radio){
            returnFixedDays.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else{
            returnFixedDays.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

However neither group is ever visible. I guess I need extra pair of eyes to spot where I'm going wrong in adding these layouts dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.return_fixed_days, null);
```

you've just inflated a layout file, you didn't actually attached it to your custom view `ReturnFixedDays`. To attach that inflated layout to your custom view you have to pass `this` as the second parameter(representing the parent of the newly inflated view hierarchy):

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.return_fixed_days, this);
```

There could be other things wrong in your code, so check and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Well spotted :-)

Comment: @peter_budo Also, as a small improvement if `R.layout.return_fixed_days` is the xml layout that you posted(with a root `RelativeLayout`) you might want to remove that parent `RelativeLayout` and replace it with a `merge` tag. Right now you're adding an extra `RelativeLayout` between `ReturnFixedDays`(which extends **RelativeLayout**) and the views from `R.layout.return_fixed_days`.

Comment: yes that is next step, I just need it to get going before I can do some code cleaning ;)